# Android & Java: Edit Text with multiple language support but few special characters

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an edit text which can take only alphabets, number, period (.) and underscore (_) without any space. I can define this in android:digits of the xml file. But, then there is no support for input using other languages. Please help. How to achieve this.

```
android:digits="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a String in values for the different languages you want:

For example:

In values/strings.xml :

```
 <string name="digits">012345</string>
```

In es/strings.xml :

```
<string name="digits">0123456789</string>
```

And then in your EditText:

```
android:digits="@string/digits"
```

Comment: I use it in my xml and it works. Do you have different folders for the strings?

Comment: I have values and values-es for language es

Comment: Ok... I use the same and when i try to enter a alphabetic value i cant because @string/digits in this example is only numeric.